# Strange behavior of $routeChangeSuccess: Not triggering on first load (but not throwing any error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no clue how to even begin explaining this situation but I'll try my best. I have a simple Spanish-English-Spanish dictionary lookup page with a text box, a **Lookup** button, and a div to show the results. When you enter a word to lookup in the text box and hit **Lookup**, the results are shown in the div below.

In the results some words are hyperlinked so when you click on them, you get the search result for the clicked word in the div. That's just like any online dictionary service functions. It works perfect except that the second functionality doesn't seem to work on the first click after a typed search. For example:

You type **pedir** in the input box and hit **Lookup**. The div below now shows the detailed meaning of **pedir** including hyperlinked words like **ask**, English for **pedir**. Now, you click **ask** which should refresh the div and show you the Spanish meanings of **ask** including words like **pedir**. However, it just refreshes the div and shows the same content as if you looked up **pedir** a second time. But when you click on **ask** a second time now, it works fine as expected. It must be noted that the words are hyperlinked appropriately and there's no mis-linking going on here. Not only that, other links (such as the ones on the navigation tab on top) also don't seem to work on first click. This happens every time a new word is looked up.

Hope the above example illustrates the problem well enough; at least that's what I have tried. My routing and controllers look like this:

```
var asApp = angular.module('asApp', ['ngRoute']);
asApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
.when('/', {
            title: 'Home of thesite – Radical Spanish learning tips and tricks for the adventurous learner',
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
// route for dictionary
        .when('/dictionary', {
            title: 'The dictionary',
            templateUrl : 'pages/dictionary.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for dictionary term
        .when('/dictionary/:word2lookup', {
            title: 'The thesite dictionary',
            templateUrl : 'pages/dictionary.html',
            controller  : 'dictController'
        })

        // route otherwise
        .otherwise({
            title: 'thesite – Radical Spanish learning tips and tricks for the adventurous learner',
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        });

});

function HeaderController($scope, $location) 
{ 
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
}

asApp.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', function($rootScope, $route, $location) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
    document.title = 'Translation of ' + $route.current.params['word2lookup'] + ' | ' + $route.current.title;
});
}]);

asApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {});
asApp.controller('dictController', function($scope, $routeParams){});
```

I don't even know if I can reproduce the entire situation in a fiddle since it involves some significant server-side scripting.

Please let me know if there's anything I could explain in order for someone to identify the gremlin breaking down my code's functionality.

**P.S.**: This issue only affects the first click (on any link on the page) *after* a new search has been performed, i.e. a word is entered in the input box and the Lookup button is clicked.

**Update**: In response to @gr3g's request, here's the code for the functions `lookup_check()` and `lookup_word()`:

```
function lookup_check(lookupterm){
    close_kb();
    if(lookupterm != ""){
        lookup_word(lookupterm);
    }
    else{
        var lookup_box = $('#word');
        lookup_box.addClass('empty');
        setTimeout(function(){ lookup_box.removeClass('empty'); },500);
    }
}
// Query dictionary and populate meaning div
function lookup_word(lookupword){
    var mean = document.getElementById('meaning');
    var waittext = '<div class="preloader-image"><br /><br />';
    var hr = createXMLHTTPRequestObject();
    var url = 'bootstrap/php/dictengine.php';
    var vars = "lookup_word=" + lookupword;
    document.getElementById('word').value = lookupword;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            mean.innerHTML = return_data;
            if ($(".el")[0]){ hist_mean = $('.el:first').text(); }
            else { hist_mean = ""; }
            add2local(lookupword, hist_mean);
            $(".tab-container").addClass("hide-tabs");
            if($("#dict_span").length != 0) {
                $(".tab-container").removeClass("hide-tabs");
                // logic to seggregate spanish and english results
                $("#dict_eng").addClass("hide-div");
                $("#sp_tab").addClass("active");
                $("#en_tab").removeClass("active");
            }
            document.title = 'Translation of ' + lookupword + ' | The thesite dictionary';
            $("<hr class='dict-divider'>").insertAfter(".gram_cat");
            $("<hr class='dict-divider'>").insertAfter(".quickdef");
            $("<hr class='dict-divider'>").insertBefore(".dict_source");
            $('div.entry_pos').wrap('<div class="pos"></div>');
            $('a.dictionary-neodict-first-part-of-speech').wrap('<div class="pos"></div>');
            // update url
            var loc = window.location.href;
            var lastpart = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            if(lastpart == 'dictionary'){ window.location.replace(window.location.href + "/" + encodeURI(lookupword)); }
            if((lastpart != 'dictionary') && (lastpart != encodeURI(lookupword))){
                var addr = window.location.href;
                var addrtemp = addr.substring(addr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                addr = addr.replace(addrtemp, encodeURI(lookupword));
                if(!!(window.history && history.pushState)){ history.pushState(null, null, addr); }
                else{ window.location.replace(addr); }
            }
        }
        //else { setTimeout('lookup_word(lookupword)', 1000); }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    mean.innerHTML = waittext;
}
```

**Update 2**: To further facilitate @gr3g, here's `dictionary.html`:

```
<!-- dictionary.html -->
<script>
    var loc = window.location.href;
    var lastpart = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if(lastpart != 'dictionary'){ lookup_check(decodeURI(lastpart)); }

    // populate search history if available
    var recent = document.getElementById('recent-lookups');
    var value = localStorage.getItem('w');
    if (value) {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
        var len = value.length - 1;
        var str = "";
        for (a=len; a>=0; a--){
            term = value[a].substr(0, value[a].indexOf('$'));
            term_meaning = value[a].substr(value[a].indexOf("$") + 1);
            if(term_meaning != "") {
            str = str + "<p><strong><a href='/a-s/#/dictionary/" + encodeURI(term) + "'>" + term + "</a></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-chevron-right' style='color: #a5a5a5;font-size: 80%;'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='recent_meanings'>" + term_meaning + "</span></p>";
        }
            else { str = str + "<p><em>" + term + "</em></p>"; }
        }
        recent.innerHTML = str;
    }
    else { recent.innerHTML = "<p>No historical data to show right now. Words will start appearing here as you begin your lookups.</p>"; }

    // populate word of the day on pageload
    wotd();

</script>

<!-- top-image start -->
<div class="page-header-line-div">
</div>
<!-- top-image end -->
<br>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="luController as luCtrl">
    <div class="row row-padding">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="lookup-form" id="lookup-form" action="" method="">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6">
                <input  id="word" type="textbox" placeholder="Enter a Spanish or English word here..." class="form-control input-lg lookup-field lookup-field-single" onMouseOver="$(this).focus();" required ng-model="luCtrl.lookuptrm">
                <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg delete-icon" onfocus="clearword();" onclick="clearword();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to clear entered text"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-2x kb-icon" onfocus="toggler('virtualkeypad', this);" onclick="toggler('virtualkeypad', this);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to enter accented characters"></i>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary lookup-submit" type="submit" id="lookup" ng-click="luCtrl.handlelookup(luCtrl.lookuptrm)">Lookup</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="virtualkeypad" class="btn-group vkb-hide"><!--col-md-offset-4-->
              <button class="btn btn-lg first-btn" type="button" onClick="spl_character('á');">á</button>
              <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('é');">é</button>
              <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('í');">í</button>
              <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ó');">ó</button>
              <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ú');">ú</button>
              <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ü');">ü</button>
              <button class="btn btn-lg last-btn" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ñ');">ñ</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- tabbed view for bilingual words -->
        <div class="col col-md-8 bi">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-container hide-tabs lang-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav active" id="sp_tab" onClick="$(this).addClass('active'); $('#en_tab').removeClass('active'); $('#dict_eng').addClass('hide-div'); $('#dict_span').removeClass('hide-div');"><a href="" data-toggle="tab">Spanish</a></li>
                <li class="nav" id="en_tab" onClick="$(this).addClass('active'); $('#sp_tab').removeClass('active'); $('#dict_span').addClass('hide-div'); $('#dict_eng').removeClass('hide-div');"><a href="" data-toggle="tab">English</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dictionary-result" id="meaning">
                <p class="box-text">This bilingual dictionary is an actively growing resource accumulating new words each day. Currently drawing from the best names in the world of Spanish/English dictionary, such as <strong>Collins</strong><sup>®</sup> and <strong>Harrap</strong><sup>®</sup>, it continues to improve with every lookup you perform. It includes regionalism, colloquialism, and other non-standard quirkiness from over a dozen Spanish dialects ranging from Peninsular to Mexican and Argentinean to Cuban. This dictionary also includes a growing number of specialty terms specific to niches such as medicine, economics, politics, etc.</p>
                <p class="box-text">Please use this page only for dictionary lookups and not comprehensive translations. You can enter either English or Spanish terms and the dictionary will automatically guess the language it belongs to. Keep your inputs to within 20 characters (that should be long enough to handle any English or Spanish word you might want to look up).</p>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- sidebar -->
        <div class="col col-md-4">
            <!-- history panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-box card-effect">
              <div class="panel-heading panel-title">Recent Lookups</div>
              <div id="recent-lookups" class="panel-body panel-text">
                No historical data to show right now. Words will start appearing here as you begin your lookups.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- WOTD panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-box card-effect">
              <div class="panel-heading panel-title">Word of the Day</div>
              <div id="wotd" class="panel-body panel-text">
                Word of the day not currently available.
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the URL change at all on the first click, or only on the second click?

Comment: do you have a working version of the page anywhere? sometimes just tracing the generated javascript with chrome debugger will tell you what the issue is, or hint to it.

Comment: @NicholasSmith The URL does change as expected but only on the second and subsequent clicks.

Comment: Can you show the html for your links?

Comment: @Nikki9696 Unfortunately, the site still sits on my localhost which is why it's so darn difficult to seek help. I don't mind sharing the files with anyone looking to help me out though but they are large and unwieldy.

Comment: @NicholasSmith: I have placed a dump of the HTML file in question here: http://pastebin.com/02BCZu4u

Comment: So, as per your example, when you click 'ask' it should've gone to  `.when('/dictionary/:word2lookup', {` , but I think its going into `.when('/dictionary', {` for some reason. So, I think you should check whether the values to `word2lookup` is getting updated/sent when you are clicking on 'ask'. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Problem is, this misrouting is also affecting clicks on non-dictionary links, such as about, home, blog, etc. The first click on any link (after performing a lookup) always refreshes the page. :(

Comment: Just for giggles, try swapping your two WHEN statements so that this one comes first .when('/dictionary/:word2lookup' and this one is after it .when('/dictionary'

Comment: Also, in the pastebin, you have a form with no action (it will submit to itself, "refreshing" the page) and an actual submit button with nothing that cancels the submit. Also just for giggles, stopPropagation or return false for that onclick.

Comment: The form doesn't have an action defined for it because I am handling the submission in the button's `onclick()`. Is that bad practice? Oh, and swapping the order of the two `.when()` statements as suggested by you didn't change the behavior. Returning false in the button's `onclick()` didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it to work!! The offending code was in the `lookup_word()` function:

```
if(!!(window.history && history.pushState)){ history.pushState(null, null, addr); }
                else{ window.location.replace(addr); }
```

I just removed the if block and replaced it with `history.pushState(null, null, addr); window.location.replace(addr);`. Don't know why or how but this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This  :

```
.otherwise({
            title: 'TheSite – Radical Spanish learning tips and tricks for the adventurous learner',
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        });
```

Can be replaced by this :

```
.otherwise("/");
```

In your HTML:
This should be avoided :

```
onclick="$('#word').blur(); lookup_check($('#word').val());"
```

You may put some JQuery events, but the values can't be passed from JQuery. 
It should look something like that :

```
onclick="$('#word').blur(); lookup_check(variableValueBindToInput)"
```

Could you show the `lookup_check` function?
And also show how you make the call to the look_up function from the link?

Here is a Plunker, using your scripts, in the angular way.
http://plnkr.co/edit/EP8y7DrTmzr0WdRkQSew?p=preview

Look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) for binding html.

Does

```
    var loc = window.location.href;
    var lastpart = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if(lastpart != 'dictionary'){ lookup_check(decodeURI(lastpart)); }
```

Makes the XHR request on page load when the link is clicked (which is setting the request words in the url)?

If this is the case, can't you use:

```
str = str + "<a ng-click='lookup_checkFromLink(request)'>";
```

And don't check on page load?
Because, in AngularJs everything inside the app (#) does not reload the whole script when changing the route, which is a core concept of Single Page Applications : not reload all content when only a part of it needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I have changed the routing code as per your advice and also posted the contents of `lookup_check()` and `lookup_word()` for your reference. I tried amending the `onclick()` code as per your instruction too but unable to get my head around how to proceed. As of now, the value does seem to be passing as expected though. Would you advice using an `ng-model` instead? Will I be able to pass that one out to the `lookup_check()` function as required?

Comment: Absolutely and this is the way to proceed. I'll post a punlkr to try to explain you how to proceed. The path to keep in mind : With JQuery, you get your variable values by selecting them. What makes Angular so interesting is the model - view binding. By having your model values in your view you need to use them...

Comment: I've added a Plunker. I'll try to solve this, but tell me : which function do you call when a link is clicked?

Comment: I implemented the `ng-click()` you suggested and it works fine although a tad contrived to someone untrained on MVC like me. The original issue of page refresh on first click remains, though and to answer your question, the links don't trigger any special function or method. If you look at the dictionary.html file, there does happen to be a bunch of JS on top of the page. I tried investigating if those were causing the problem but couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: gr3g: Just wanted to thank you once again for your efforts. Really appreciate your help. Also want you to know that if you see this through and help me get this issue resolved, it'll be a real big deal to me. So big, I promise you additional 50 bounty points (over and above the prevailing bounty) for your help!

Comment: input type="textbox" does not exist. I saw a lot of problems and made a new plunker based on your script you made available. Please see updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately, binding results to the `meaning` div's <p> tag didn't help matters because once I did that, it started showing the returned file as an XML dump, tags intact. So I had to roll back the changes. I did implement other changes like the ones to the form submit button though but the problem of unresponsive first click persists.

Comment: The reason I am performing the check upon page reload is to handle cases where a user enters a direct URL in the form of `www.mysite.com/dictionary/word`. If I don't perform that check, the page will always open with the blank form for the user to manually enter the word to lookup. And not sure I understand your suggestion about `str = str + "<a ng-click='lookup_checkFromLink(request)'>";`. What's this variable and where have we defined it?

Comment: Ok. If you put the code online I'll be able to find to issue pretty quickly, but for know I can only recommend you to debug by setting break points in the console (especially in the lookup_function to see if it gets there)

Comment: What if I sent you the files. Will that be any help? I don't know how to put this up in a fiddle given its server-side dependencies.

Comment: It depends if I can run your app in localhost without external dependencies?